# android ProgressBar is missing percentage information

Tags: android, progress-bar

As part of my activity view I put the following progress bar:

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" 
            android:progress="0"
            android:max="100"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

The problem is that I expected that under it, the percentage values (text) will be displayed. However they are missing. There is only pure bar. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Android's `ProgressBar` just doesn't support that. You can, however, add your own `TextView` and update it whenever you update the progress.

Comment: It's always more elegant to use solutions from the shelf. But thank you for the answer.